# vb cant connect to access 2007 db

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2007

**WHY WONT THIS JUST WORK ? The code is not working due to some connection string error could be an out of date driver not sure please help any advice much good help yes i have tried using Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; still no work **

```
    'Connects to the Access driver and Access database in the Inetpub
    'directory where the database is saved
    strProvider = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=D:\HostingSpaces\E2ESolutions\ryan.e2e.uk.com\wwwroot\asp\guestbook.mdb;"
    'strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\HostingSpaces\E2ESolutions\ryan.e2e.uk.com\wwwroot\asp\guestbook.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    'Creates an instance of an Active Server component
    set objConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    'Opens the connection to the data store
    'objConn.Open strProvider
    'Instantiate Command object and use ActiveConnection property to
    'attach connection to Command object
    response.Write("working")
    set cm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cm.ActiveConnection = objConn
    'Define SQL query
    cm.CommandText ="INSERT INTO Guestbook (TB1,TB2,TB3,TB4,MB1)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
    'Define query parameter configuration information for guestbook fields
    set objparam=cm.createparameter(, 200, , 255, strTB1)
    cm.parameters.append objparam
    set objparam=cm.createparameter(, 200, , 255, strTB2)
    cm.parameters.append objparam
    set objparam=cm.createparameter(, 200, , 255, strTB3)
    cm.parameters.append objparam
    set objparam=cm.createparameter(, 200, , 255, strTB4)
    cm.parameters.append objparam
    set objparam=cm.createparameter(, 201, , iLenMB1, strMB1)
    cm.parameters.append objparam
    cm.execute
    response.write("Thank you!")
    ELSE
    %>
    <h1>Guestbook</h1>
    <!--Post information to Guestbook form -->
    <form action=""  method="POST">
    <p>To</p>
    <p><input type="Text" name="To"></p>
    <p>Email Address</p>
    <p><input type="Text" name="EmailAdd"></p>
    <p> CC</p>
    <p><input type="Text" name="CC"></p>
    <p>Subject</p>
    <p><input type="Text" name="Subject"></p>
    <p>Message</p>
    <p><textarea name="Memo" rows=6 cols=70></textarea></p>
    <input  type="HIDDEN" name="Message" value="True">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit information">
    </form>
    <%
    End if
    %>
    </body>
    </html>
    }
```

Comment: i know its to do with the connection string thats it

Answer (score 0):

Well, your connection string is not very well constructed. You need to reference connectionstrings [Click Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) and try out a few their.

e.g.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

---

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

---

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;
```

---

**ALSO** - You are never establishing a connection to your database.

e.g.

```
strProvider = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=D:\HostingSpaces\E2ESolutions\ryan.e2e.uk.com\wwwroot\asp\guestbook.mdb;"


'What was wrong with this connection string?
    'strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\HostingSpaces\E2ESolutions\ryan.e2e.uk.com\wwwroot\asp\guestbook.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"


    'Creates an instance of an Active Server component
    set objConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")


    'Uncomment here to test connection string. 
    'Opens the connection to the data store
    objConn.Open strProvider
```